# In Material UI v3.6.0 Select Dropdown div flickers / triggers twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When i am providing less than 100 items to the Select Dropdown its working fine but if i provide more than 100 then the Dropdown flickers/triggers twice.
I have checked by putting debug point in the render function but it doesn't reach there after first render.
I also put a random no check to see whether its actually re-rendering but even the randomly generated no is same.
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

class SimpleSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    age: '',
    name: 'hai',
    labelWidth: 0,
  };

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.filters = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      labelWidth: 0,
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
      this.filters.push('----select----' + i);
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Filter</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: 'age',
              id: 'age-simple',
            }}
          >
            {this.filters && this.filters.map((filter, index) => (
                        <MenuItem key={'filter-' + index} value={filter}>
                            {filter}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

SimpleSelect.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleSelect);
```

This behavior is only observed in material-ui v3.6.0.

**Edit1:** Please have a look at the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-architecture-w0rdv)

Comment: I looked and tried the codesandbox and it is not triggering/flickering twice. Tested it on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge. Any more information you can provide for your environment?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the long array, i tried to reduce the number of iterations to 50 and is not flickering or triggering twice. Try move the for loop into higher component and pass the props filter array into the child with componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: The behavior seems to persist through v3.9.4, but does not exist in v4. Looks like a reason to upgrade (or just live with it if you can't upgrade yet for some reason).